# android studio move code fragment with drag-and-drop not working correctly

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

move code fragment with drag-and-drop is checked in android studio settings

but it's not working[image]

here is version

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins and restart? If the problem remains please raise a new issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new and provide a short video showing the problem.

Comment: thank you, it fixed after i disabled "Markdown Image Support" plugin